# Is it possible to schedule Groovy Script in SOAP UI?

Tags: testing, groovy, scripting, soapui

I have Groovy Script in my Test Case in SOAP UI. 
There are one big script and a lot of test steps which are run by this script. I know about functionality of TestRunner but it run all steps in test case, but i need to run only my groovy script. How?

**UPDATE**
I disable all Test steps and left active only groovy script. Then I Launch TestRunner on Test Case, it return exception :

```
java.lang.Exception: TestCase [Case1] failed without assertions

    at com.eviware.soapui.tools.SoapUITestCaseRunner.throwFailureException(SoapUITestCaseRunner.java:535)
    at com.eviware.soapui.tools.SoapUITestCaseRunner.runRunner(SoapUITestCaseRunner.java:437)
    at com.eviware.soapui.tools.AbstractSoapUIRunner.run(AbstractSoapUIRunner.java:162)
    at com.eviware.soapui.tools.AbstractSoapUIRunner.runFromCommandLine(AbstractSoapUIRunner.java:93)
    at com.eviware.soapui.tools.SoapUITestCaseRunner.main(SoapUITestCaseRunner.java:119)
```

Comment: Do you have other test steps in your test case along with the groovy script?

Comment: I have more than 30 test steps, but i use only 22 and they are run by this Groovy script.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable the rest of the steps and run the test case. The disabled test steps are not run automatically by soapui, you can call those conditionally :)

Comment: 10:22:19,196 ERROR [SoapUI] An error occurred [TestCase [CASE1] failed without assertions
], see error log for details
java.lang.Exception: TestCase [CASE1] failed without assertions

 at com.eviware.soapui.tools.SoapUITestCaseRunner.throwFailureException(SoapUITestCaseRunner.java:535)
 at com.eviware.soapui.tools.SoapUITestCaseRunner.runRunner(SoapUITestCaseRunner.java:437)
 at com.eviware.soapui.tools.AbstractSoapUIRunner.run(AbstractSoapUIRunner.java:162)
 at com.eviware.soapui.tools.AbstractSoapUIRunner.runFromCommandLine(AbstractSoapUIRunner.java:93)
 at com.eviware.soapui.tools.....

Comment: did you see the error log file?? Just check if your main script gets any parameters from disabled scripts. Just by seeing this trace, can't make out what the problem is :)